# Converting list of integers to string

Tags: python, string, sockets

I am trying to use the socket.sendto function to send a block of random bytes in a UDP packet.  I can generate the random bytes, but it looks like sendto requires the data to be a string.  I am going to generate thousands of these packets for test purposes, so I need a technique that is memory efficient.  Can anyone tell me of a function that will take a list of integers (range 256) and convert to a (non-comma-separated) string?  On the receiving end, I will use c code to look at the raw bytes.

Comment: First get the list of integers and then use str() on the list? [str(num) for num in list]?

Comment: *I am going to generate thousands of these packets for test purposes, so I need a technique that is memory efficient* - oh no, thousands! I can see how that could be a problem for a modern computer. Who has more than one kilobyte of memory spare?

Answer (score 1):

You might find an [array.array.tobytes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html#array.array.tobytes) useful:

```
from array import array

b = array("B", range(256)).tobytes() # tostring python2
```

`B` is an unsigned char [type](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html#module-array) which will work for your range

Comment: In Python 2.7 I get this message:  'array.array' object has no attribute 'tobytes'

Comment: @JimBob, `array("h", l).tostring()` in python2

Comment: Thanks-that works after I realized I took my ascii codes from the wrong column of the ASCII table.  I assume "h" means hex.

Comment: @JimBob, it is a type code  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html#module-array, it should also be a `B`

Comment: Thanks again - that gives me exactly what I want!

Comment: No worries, it is about as efficient as you will get!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I finally caught up.
You want a byte array. Passing a list of ints into a `bytes` constructor will create a byte array.

For example, writing binary codes to a file:

```
   with open('rawfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(bytes([1,2,3]))
        ...
        f.write(bytes([3,5,254]))
        ...
        f.write(bytes([54, 65, 73, 74]))
```

You may have to worry about encoding, big-endian, little-endian, etc.

To encode this into a string, just build the string afterwards, however, it sounds like the bytearray is probably what you want to send.

```
>>> print(bytes([84, 69, 83, 84]))
b'TEST'
>>> print(bytes([1,2,3]))
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>> str(bytes([1,2,3]))
"b'\\x01\\x02\\x03'"
```

Warning: most functions that are expecting a string will balk at a bytearray. But you can try it. There is a big difference between `b'\x01\x02\x03'` and `"b'\\x01\\x02\\x03'"`

Comment: [54, 65, 73, 74]  would become "Test" Some of the characters in the string would be non-printable control characters.  Again, my goal is to send RAW bytes.

Comment: I think I got it. See updated answer. Although `[54, 65, 73, 74] ` is not ascii for 'Test' so maybe I'm still off.